# Django queryset how to exclude products with no group or tags?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

Starting from **Group**, I want to return a `queryset` of items, but exclude the Group from the queryset if it doesn't have a **product** with a tag assigned to it.

Models

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    group = models.ForeignKey('Group', related_name='tags')

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', related_name='products')
```

This is what I have tried:

```
Group.objects.all().exclude(tags__products__isnull=True)
```

Above does not appear to return the correct result. If I have 2 products with the tags `Red` and `200cm` in Groups `color` and `width`. One product has the tag red, but the other product has no tags assigned to a group, so I expect 1 group to be returned. Above incorrectly gives meI get 0?

Another example

```
Group 1 Color
Group 2 Width

Tag Red - FK to Group 1

Product 1 FK to tag Red
```

The result should be that only Group 1 is shown because Group 2 has no products with tags.

Comment: DO you have another tag in Group 'color' other than red?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour you describe could be explained if there is another `Tag` in the `'color'` `Group`. If that tag has no products, your `exclude` would correctly exclude the color group because of that tag. You should approach it the other way round:

```
Group.objects.filter(tags__products__isnull=False)  
# one tag with a product suffices to include the group -> intended!
```

instead of

```
Group.objects.exclude(tags__products__isnull=True)  
# one tag WITHOUT a product suffices to exclude the group
# even if other tags of the group have products -> not intended!
```

Comment: Cool, I've just come to the same conclusion, however I did the following ``.filter(tags__products__gt=0)`` - which is better?

Comment: From all examples I have seen, I think `__isnull` is the common way to go. Whether it performs better than your solution or not, idk. You can inspect the SQL it produces via: `print queryset.query`

Answer (score -1):

```
Group.objects.all().exclude(tags__products__name='')
```

Django documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null

Comment: You can reverse query: Product.objects.values('product__tags__name','product__tags__group','product__tags__name')

Comment: I have to start at Group, the other way around I can do it. What you posted will never work as all products have ``names``!